# How to provide unique IDs to codeception testcases?

Tags: php, automated-tests, codeception

I have testcases which I'm automating and they have unique IDs.

```
//Plain English testcase
ID: 1234
1. Go to url: "example.com"
2. Click on button named: "Don't click me"
3. See if the button got angry
```

Where can I include the above test-case's ID into automated version of that testcase(located below)?

```
//Automated version of the above testcase
$I = new AcceptanceTester($scenario);
$I->amOnUrl("example.com");
$I->see("Don't click me");
$I->click("#angry_button");
$I->see('......') // some result
```

Keep in mind, that ID must be present in an xml report, whenever the former is generated:

```
codecept run acceptance --xml
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$I->wantTo("Test ID: 1234");
```

But if you are referring to a unique ID per test case execution you can just use date as a workaround.

For example:

```
$time = date("m-j-Y-G:i:s");
$I->wantTo("Test ID ".$time);
```

Comment: Seems a bit hacky to me. Will the ID be present in generated reports with --html or --xml flags?

Answer (score 0):

Start using Cest test cases in codeception.  This will make your life sooo much easier.  Trust me, I allso started off with Cept.

So, when you do use Cest, you can do the following:

Use your function name as the unique id.
In my test I have:

```
public function testPageElementsAvailability(AcceptanceTester $I)
{ 
  test some thing
}
```

This produces the following xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<testsuites>
  <testsuite name="acceptance" tests="1" assertions="1" failures="0" errors="0" time="3.954338">
    <testcase file="..../createCest.php" name="testPageElementsAvailability" class="post\createCest" feature="test page elements availability" assertions="1" time="3.954338"/>
 </testsuite>
</testsuites>
```